# Not getting the formatted text

Tags: android

I'm trying to read a .txt file. but in the textview the text in not formatted. i,e there is no new line in the textview even if i have given the new line. The sentences are continuous. Is it possible to format? the code goes like this

```
final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    try{
        DataInputStream dataIO= new DataInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.chapter1));
        String strLine= null;
        while((strLine = dataIO.readLine())!=null){
            buffer.append(strLine);
        }
        dataIO.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.chapter);
    tv.setText(buffer.toString());


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the documentation of [DataInputStream.readLine()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29)

> The string does not include the newline sequence.

So the `strLine`, which you are appending to the `StringBuffer` will not contain the newline.
You can modify your code as follows:

```
    while((strLine = dataIO.readLine())!=null){
        buffer.append(strLine);
        buffer.append('\n');
    }
```

Comment: Please give some suggestions about opening the file dynamically. I mean, I have saved a bunch of chapters in raw folder. Once from the list of chapters, if user select chapter1 the R.raw should load the chapter1 file at the end.If chapter2 then chapter2 and so on. Please help me out in this one.

Comment: Please post it as a new question as it is unrelated to the current topic.

Answer (score 0):

Store your file content in a string after reading the file as follow ::

```
String fileContent = buffer.toString().replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "<br />");
```

Then, in your text view set text as HTML :

```
txtview.setText(Html.fromHtml(fileContent));
```

Comment: Why there is extra closing bracket in the fileContent.

Comment: I didn't get the fileContent line. Please make it in a syntactical way so that I can use it. Thank you.

Comment: Oh...Sorry...my mistake....edited the answer.....let me know whether u r getting expected results or not....

Comment: Nop. I didn't get the new line.

Comment: Rajesh is right...DataInputStream.readLine() will not include new line character, So my solution won't work as replaceAll will not find any "\\n" character...So u can either use Rajesh's solution directly or after getting string with "\n" character using @Rajesh's solution, you can display as HTL in textview.

Comment: @Rajesh Please check this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153733/not-getting-the-package-name