# Not getting the package name

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve the file from the raw folder dynamically the code as below

```
try{
        DataInputStream dataIO= new DataInputStream(getResources().getIdentifier("raw/"+chapter, null ,<what to write>);
        String strLine= null;
        while((strLine = dataIO.readLine())!=null){
            buffer.append(strLine);
            buffer.append("\n");
        }
        dataIO.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}
```

If I type the package name directly in the "what to write" section, it showing the error. Please give some idea about it.

Comment: what error? show the stacktrace

Comment: I mean syntax error. My package name is com.expandableList. If I write the "com.expandableList" in the package area. It is showing red colored underline.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to retrieve the id of a raw resource dynamically, the following code snippet would be useful:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(chapter, "raw", getPackageName());
```

and your DataInputStream object should be constructed thus:

```
DataInputStream dataIO= new DataInputStream(getResources().openRawResource(id));
```

Comment: I'm very new to the android. So please give me some suggestion about how to improve the skills. Is it really necessary to master the core java for it.

Comment: Well, having mastery over the Java language definitely helps, but you can improve as you learn new things. Get hold of a good book (refer to the list of book recommendations on the android tag's [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) page) and read and try out stuff mentioned in the book.

Answer (score 0):

A fully qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry", which is missing in your code. I use the below code to access raw resource.

getResources().getIdentifier("package:type/entry", null, null);